# Setup Qt environment for android development

Tags: android, qt

I've heard a lot about Qt so I wanted to give it a try. Unfortunately I ran into a problem at the start..

First of all I set up the environment according to the offical qt guide: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html

When I trying to build the "cellphone" example which is found on the Welcome page, I'm getting this error which helps me nearly nothing:

```
:-1: error: [qrc_cellphone.cpp] Error 1
```

This is the compile output:

```
20:23:41: Running steps for project cellphone...
20:23:41: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
20:23:41: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/opt/Qt/5.6/android_armv7/bin/rcc -name cellphone ../cellphone/cellphone.qrc -o qrc_cellphone.cpp
RCC: Error in '../cellphone/cellphone.qrc': Cannot find file '../../3rdparty/three.js'
Makefile:509: recipe for target 'qrc_cellphone.cpp' failed
make: *** [qrc_cellphone.cpp] Error 1
20:23:42: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project cellphone (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.6.0))
When executing step "Make"
20:23:42: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

When I trying to create and build Qt Quick application I'm getting these two errors:

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lGL
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

For this one the compile output:

```
20:26:01: Running steps for project QtQuickTest...
20:26:01: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
20:26:01: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -Wl,-z,origin -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/lib -o QtQuickTest main.o qrc_qml.o   -L/opt/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Quick -lQt5Gui -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
Makefile:198: recipe for target 'QtQuickTest' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [QtQuickTest] Error 1
20:26:01: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project QtQuickTest (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
20:26:01: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

My os is kubuntu if it matters. What did I miss?

Thanks in advance!

Edit after user12345's answer:

Now at least the Quick project works for desktop. But I'm getting this error message when I'm trying to build for android:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/nandor/Programs/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/nandor/Programs/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:694: null returned: 1

Total time: 0 seconds
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
16:28:36: The process "/opt/Qt/5.6/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project QtQuickTest (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.6.0))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
```

However the cellphone built in example still giving the same error message. I don't know where should I get or find that ../../3rdparty/three.js file and why this isn't included in the project. Anyway I guess it's not related to the main question I guess however I'm happy if you can answer. :)

Edit 2:
[image: android api version]

These are the 648-650 lines in the build.xml:

```
<do-only-if-manifest-hasCode
                elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping aidl/renderscript/R.java">
            <echo level="info">Handling aidl files...</echo>
```

And 694:

```
proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt">
```

Comment: I've edited my question and added compile outputs.

Comment: Does it build fine for the desktop version ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I just realized from the compile output, my second try was with Desktop kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel we need to go step by step and try to resolve the errors that you are observing. I see that you are using the Qt 5.6.0, I will suggest you to update your `Mesa Package` on your Ubuntu machine by executing the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

This should resolve the sort of errors like below that you are observing:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
```

After that try to clean and rebuild the desktop version, and see what you find.

**Coming to your Android Build error:**

My Guess will be that you might have set build settings of your android kit wrongly. I will suggest you to change the `Android build SDK` to `android-23` as shown in the attached picture below:

[image: build settings]

Comment: Please see my main question's edit section. I couldn't answer here, because it was too long.

Comment: are you using some examples qt program from Welcome page of Qt Creator or was it your own application. If it is built in example - can you tell me what is that example.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The quick project that I mention is a self made, but with the starter code. So it's basically a hello world. This is working on desktop after installing libgl1-mesa-dev. But it has got problems on android with the error that I linked in the edit section. The examples I mention are the build in examples in Qt creator. Their names are "cellphone" and "planets" both of them are in the first line of the list, and both of them are missing the same file as I see. (../../3dparty/three.js)

Comment: Check my update to the answer and let me know if that fixes your problem. Cheers !

Comment: It took time to find that menu... No prob at least I've learnt it. So the only version is android-15 there for me, because I've only installed API 15 since I wanted to build for 4.0.3. Is it a problem? See my edit please.

Comment: You were right! I've installed api 23 and now it works. However it's sad because I wanted to target android 4.0.3. Does that means that I can only target higher android versions with qt?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason why it is not working with older android versions. Maybe you may want to post another question regarding the build issues with old target vs latest.

Comment: While I try to run qml on Android arm7 API 15 I have got that kind of errors too besides another errors like ndk root path error Qt version qmake error even though qml apps run well on the desktop debugging. It doesn't make sense that can be done only with API 23.. whenever I try to run "hello world" app using Qt5 on android I always fail first times. Setting up QT for Android is harder than making apps for Android:(